# Output SQL single transactions that has multiple sales items that belonging to different item group configurations

Tags: sql-server

I need a query that can return a transaction that has multiple items. The transaction must have multiple items that belong to a combination of the buckets below:

100 Items are grouped into three buckets. Bucket 49, bucket 50, and bucket 56.

There is item 1 configured with bucket 49.

There is a item 2 configured with bucket 50.

And finally the rest of the items are configured with bucket 56.

Looking for query to select transaction with combo:-

Transaction include = 1 item (49) and 1 item (56)

or

Transaction include = 1 item (50) and 1 item (56)

This is what I have tried

```
**`select 
    INVENTTABLE.[COSTGROUPID],
    INVENTTABLE.[NAMEALIAS],
    #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.STORE,
    #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSACTIONID,
    sum(#temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.PRICE) as Transaction_Sum
from #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime 
join INVENTTABLE
    on INVENTTABLE.[ITEMID] = #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.[ITEMID]
where [COSTGROUPID] in ('56', '49', '50')
and cast(#temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSDATE as date) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-28'
and #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.ITEMID in ('I00075431', 'I00075432')
group by INVENTTABLE.[COSTGROUPID],
    INVENTTABLE.[NAMEALIAS],
    #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.STORE,
    #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSACTION_ID
order by Transaction_Sum desc;`**
```

Every transaction that I look up has only item figuration bucket for either 56 or 49 or 50.

But not combination

Transaction includes = 1 item (49) and 1 item (56)

or

Transaction includes = 1 item (50) and 1 item (56)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below -

```
select 
    INVENTTABLE.[COSTGROUPID],
    INVENTTABLE.[NAMEALIAS],
    #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.STORE,
    #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSACTIONID,
    sum(#temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.PRICE) as Transaction_Sum
from #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime 
join INVENTTABLE
    on INVENTTABLE.[ITEMID] = #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.[ITEMID]
where ([COSTGROUPID] ='56' AND [COSTGROUPID] ='49' AND [COSTGROUPID] ='50')
and cast(#temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSDATE as date) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-28'
and #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.ITEMID in ('I00075431', 'I00075432')

UNION ALL

select 
    INVENTTABLE.[COSTGROUPID],
    INVENTTABLE.[NAMEALIAS],
    #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.STORE,
    #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSACTIONID,
    sum(#temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.PRICE) as Transaction_Sum
from #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime 
join INVENTTABLE
    on INVENTTABLE.[ITEMID] = #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.[ITEMID]
where ([COSTGROUPID] ='56' AND [COSTGROUPID] ='50')
and cast(#temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSDATE as date) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-28'
and #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.ITEMID in ('I00075431', 'I00075432')

UNION ALL 

select 
        INVENTTABLE.[COSTGROUPID],
        INVENTTABLE.[NAMEALIAS],
        #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.STORE,
        #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSACTIONID,
        sum(#temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.PRICE) as Transaction_Sum
    from #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime 
    join INVENTTABLE
        on INVENTTABLE.[ITEMID] = #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.[ITEMID]
    where ([COSTGROUPID] ='49' AND [COSTGROUPID] ='50')
    and cast(#temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSDATE as date) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-28'
    and #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.ITEMID in ('I00075431', 'I00075432')

UNION ALL

select 
        INVENTTABLE.[COSTGROUPID],
        INVENTTABLE.[NAMEALIAS],
        #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.STORE,
        #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSACTIONID,
        sum(#temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.PRICE) as Transaction_Sum
    from #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime 
    join INVENTTABLE
        on INVENTTABLE.[ITEMID] = #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.[ITEMID]
    where ([COSTGROUPID] ='56' AND [COSTGROUPID] ='49')
    and cast(#temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSDATE as date) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-05-28'
    and #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.ITEMID in ('I00075431', 'I00075432')

group by INVENTTABLE.[COSTGROUPID],
    INVENTTABLE.[NAMEALIAS],
    #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.STORE,
    #temp_whatIWantForRealsThisTime.TRANSACTION_ID
order by Transaction_Sum desc;
```

Comment: Hi Aagam, thanks for looking into that query. Unfortunately, the bottom three unions do not produce any results so the first query is the only query that produces results.

Comment: Hi Dennis, sorry for the same. I have edited the query accordingly. Please try now if you haven't yet found a solution.

Comment: Thanks Aagam. After looking at your approach, it triggered this approach and after I ran this I received the results.

Comment: Thanks @Aagam. You definitely inspired the defined solution!